# Spacemacs and Orgmode: Bulk unschedule a task from the Agenda view

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-agenda

I was looking for a way to bulk unschedule tasks from the agenda view. There is a function included in `org-mode` for `bulk-unschedule` according to [Carsten Dominik](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-01/msg00399.html), but was not sure how to find this in `Spacemacs.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The solutions is to use `SPC u B s`. You mark the items you want to unschedule and then use this key combination to bulk unschedule them.